# How can I change the CSS properties of an imported component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I change the CSS properties of an imported component in React? I am trying to make a function that works like: onclick = increases the size of the component clicked, and when clicked away it goes back to normal.

I have implemented this before directly accessing the DOM in vanilla javascript, but I do not know how to do this in react.

Currently, I have an empty function

```
function appcardWasClicked() {

}
```

and the components in a div set to onClick={appcardWasClicked()}:

```
<div className="Appreviewcard-index">
        <Appreviewcard onClick={appcardWasClicked()}/>
        <Appreviewcard onClick={appcardWasClicked()}/>
        <Appreviewcard onClick={appcardWasClicked()}/>
  </div>
```

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

import Bottom from '../components/Home/bottom-nav'
import Firstparagraph from '../components/Home/first-paragraph'
import Appfeatures from '../components/Home/app-features'
import Appworks from '../components/Home/app-works'
import Extrafeatures from '../components/Home/extra-features'
import Appreview from '../components/Home/app-review'
import Appreviewcard from '../components/Home/app-review-card'
import Header from '../components/Home/header'





const PageIndex = ({ data, location }) => {
  const siteTitle = data.site.siteMetadata.title
  
  function appcardWasClicked() {
    
  }

  return (
    <Layout location={location} title={siteTitle}>
      <SEO title="All posts" />
      <Header />
      <Firstparagraph />
      <Appfeatures />
      <Appworks />
      <Extrafeatures />
      <Appreview />
      <div className="Appreviewcard-index">
        <Appreviewcard onClick={appcardWasClicked()}/>
        <Appreviewcard onClick={appcardWasClicked()}/>
        <Appreviewcard onClick={appcardWasClicked()}/>
      </div>
      <Bottom />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default PageIndex


export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

app-review-card.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import person1 from "../../images/myself.jpg"



export class Appreviewcard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Appreviewcard">
                <div className="Appreviewcard-main">
                    <div className="Appreviewcard-main-picture">
                        <img src={person1} alt="person" className="Appreviewcard-main-picture-img"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="Appreviewcard-main-text"> 
                        <h1 className="Appreviewcard-main-text-h1">John Deo</h1>
                        <p className="Appreviewcard-main-text-h3">CEO, ABC Company</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="Appreviewcard-secondary">
                    <p className="Appreviewcard-secondary-h2">Lorem Ispum dollar ispestum sosad Lorem Ispum dollar ispestum sosad Lorem Ispum dollar ispestum sosad Lorem Ispum dollar ispestum sosad</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Appreviewcard
```

Comment: if you move ```appcardWasClicked``` into Appreviewcard it's should work like vanilla i think 
```   <div className="Appreviewcard " onClick={appcardWasClicked()}>```

Comment: Okay, I moved it to app-review-card, but how would I change the css property for height and width. Like what would the syntax look like.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the Clicked div through the function. For that, You event to pass an event like bellow:

```
<Appreviewcard onClick={(e) =>appcardWasClicked(e)}/>
```

Also receive that event and get the element from it, and than apply css with vanila js as you have done it before.

```
function appcardWasClicked(e) {
    const element = e.target;
    //here write your desired css with vanillaJs

  }
```

Comment: so in vanilla javascript it would look like this ```document.getElementById("lefteye").style.backgroundColor = "purple";``` Can you give an example on the syntax I would use in here. like ```style.backgroundColor = 'blue';``` (Not sure if that is correct syntax just saying for example, if it is)

Comment: You can try `e.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue;")`

Comment: The code ```const element = e.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue;");``` was not changing anything when I tried clicking on the Appreviewcards. I also tried putting it into a new line and keeping the first line ```e.target.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue;");``` and using element ```element.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue;");``` None of which worked on click

Comment: Can you get the element by `console.log(e.target)`?

Comment: when I do ```console.log(e.target)``` in the function, nothing shows up in console when I click on the Appreviewcards

Comment: Its weird. Can you please share you code in some where like jsfiddle?

Comment: trying to upload my files to codesandbox right now, think I willd just have to copy and past a lot

Comment: Here is the code I was able to upload it https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-christian-nxpmm?file=/src/components/layout.js

Comment: It says 502 bad gateway

Comment: STill its 502 :(

Comment: Okay so the best way I can think to do this is if you clone the github repository and just use, "gatsby develop" to run the proeject. It's a longer way but code sandbox refuses to work. Here is the link https://github.com/Calebm5577/tictic-repo

Comment: An update to this: I found out that if I put the onClick function to the parent div then I cosole.log(e.target) I get Appreviewcard-main in the console

Comment: So I messed around with it and some properties only effect one of the Appcard's while others effect them all. Also the background counts a something in the div. Here is a short video showing what I mean. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-5twkcJmrQ&feature=youtu.be  Not sure if there is a good solution to this. Maybe adding IDs to the appcards or setting up the function different. But if there is not a good solution I can look into rebuilding it differently from the way I have it and close the question.